# OpenCL uses sub-buffer's parent for constant parameter

Tags: opencl, gpgpu

I have an OpenCL (1.2) kernel that takes a `constant` argument, which is a sub-buffer. When I run this kernel, it seems like the parent buffer is used instead. If I use a `global const` argument, it works as expected.

I would put this down to a driver bug, except I can reproduce it on both Intel (Linux, beignet git) and nVidia (Linux, 367.44-3) implementations on different machines, which makes me think I've made a mistake somewhere.

Below is a working example. The expected output is `1, 1025, 1, 1025,`, but instead `1, 1, 1, 1025,` is printed.

```
#include <CL/cl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NELEMS(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof(*x))

#define PLATFORM 0
#define DEVICE 0

const char src[] =
    "kernel void test1(constant int * const a) {\n"
    "    size_t i = get_global_id(0);\n"
    "    if (i == 1)\n"
    "        printf(\"%i, \", a[i]);\n"
    "}\n"
    "\n"
    "kernel void test2(global const int * const a) {\n"
    "    size_t i = get_global_id(0);\n"
    "    if (i == 1)\n"
    "        printf(\"%i, \", a[i]);\n"
    "}\n";
const size_t src_len = sizeof(src);
const char * const kernels[] = {"test1", "test2"};

int main(void) {
    cl_int err = -1;

    cl_uint num_platforms;
    clGetPlatformIDs(0, NULL, &num_platforms);
    assert(num_platforms > PLATFORM);

    cl_platform_id  * platforms = malloc(sizeof(*platforms) * num_platforms);
    clGetPlatformIDs(num_platforms, platforms, NULL);

    cl_uint num_devices;
    clGetDeviceIDs(platforms[PLATFORM], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, 0, NULL, &num_devices);
    assert(num_devices >= DEVICE);

    cl_device_id * devices = malloc(sizeof(*devices) * num_devices);
    clGetDeviceIDs(platforms[PLATFORM], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, num_devices, devices, NULL);

    cl_context_properties context_properties[] = {
        CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, (cl_context_properties) platforms[PLATFORM], 0
    };

    cl_context context = clCreateContext(context_properties, 1, &devices[DEVICE], NULL, NULL, &err);
    assert(err == CL_SUCCESS);

#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
    cl_command_queue queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, devices[DEVICE], 0, &err);
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
    assert(err == CL_SUCCESS);

    cl_program program;
    {
        // Crashes if directly using src[]
        char * source = malloc(src_len);
        memcpy(source, src, src_len);
        program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char **) &source, &src_len, &err);
        assert(err == CL_SUCCESS);
        free(source);
    }

    err = clBuildProgram(program, 1, &devices[DEVICE], "", NULL, NULL);
    assert(err == CL_SUCCESS);

    size_t buffer_size = 8192;
    size_t subbuffer_size = buffer_size / 2;
    {
        cl_uint align;
        err = clGetDeviceInfo(devices[DEVICE], CL_DEVICE_MEM_BASE_ADDR_ALIGN, sizeof(align), &align, NULL);
        assert(err == CL_SUCCESS);
        assert(subbuffer_size % align == 0);

        cl_ulong constbuf_size;
        err = clGetDeviceInfo(devices[DEVICE], CL_DEVICE_MAX_CONSTANT_BUFFER_SIZE, sizeof(constbuf_size), &constbuf_size, NULL);
        assert(err == CL_SUCCESS);
        assert(constbuf_size > subbuffer_size);
    }
    cl_mem buffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_HOST_WRITE_ONLY, buffer_size, NULL, &err);
    assert(err == CL_SUCCESS);

    cl_mem sub_buffers[2];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < NELEMS(sub_buffers); i++){
        cl_buffer_region region = {
            .origin = i * subbuffer_size,
            .size = subbuffer_size,
        };
        sub_buffers[i] = clCreateSubBuffer(buffer, 0, CL_BUFFER_CREATE_TYPE_REGION, &region, &err);
        assert(err == CL_SUCCESS);
    }

    {
        cl_int * data = clEnqueueMapBuffer(queue, buffer, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_WRITE_INVALIDATE_REGION, 0, buffer_size, 0, NULL, NULL, &err);
        assert(err == CL_SUCCESS);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < buffer_size / sizeof(cl_int); i++)
            data[i] = i;
        cl_event unmap_event;
        err = clEnqueueUnmapMemObject(queue, buffer, data, 0, NULL, &unmap_event);
        assert(err == CL_SUCCESS);
        err = clWaitForEvents(1, &unmap_event);
        assert(err == CL_SUCCESS);
    }

    for (size_t k = 0; k < NELEMS(kernels); k++) {
        cl_kernel kernel = clCreateKernel(program, kernels[k], &err);
        assert(err == CL_SUCCESS);

        cl_event run_event;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < NELEMS(sub_buffers); i++){
            err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &sub_buffers[i]);
            assert(err == CL_SUCCESS);
            size_t work_size[] = {subbuffer_size / sizeof(cl_int)};
            err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 1, NULL, work_size, NULL, 0, NULL, &run_event);
            assert(err == CL_SUCCESS);
            err = clWaitForEvents(1, &run_event);
            assert(err == CL_SUCCESS);
            err = clFinish(queue);
            assert(err == CL_SUCCESS);
        }

        clReleaseKernel(kernel);
    }
    puts("");

    for (size_t i = 0; i < NELEMS(sub_buffers); i++)
        clReleaseMemObject(sub_buffers[i]);
    clReleaseMemObject(buffer);
    clReleaseProgram(program);
    clReleaseCommandQueue(queue);
    clReleaseContext(context);

    free(devices);
    free(platforms);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is interesting.  I try it on difference devices, in a MacBookPro there are 3 devices include Nvidia IRIS and Intel, all get correct output.  In the windows 10 in this MBP with Nvidia driver, the output is exactly same wrong.
I think it's a Nvidia bug, but not limit to Nvidia.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll contact the vendors and see if I get more information.